# How to map a parameter pack using a member function? (non-recursive, pre-fold expressions)

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

In C++17, fold expressions allow you to map parameter packs, calling a member function on each, before passing them on into another function:

```
template <typename... Ts>
double func(const Ts&... ts) { ... }

template <typename... Us>
double func2(const Us&... us)
{
    // assume all member_func return types are non-void
    return func((us.member_func(1), ...));
}
```

Is it possible to achieve a similar, non-recursive mapping in C++14?

Comment: You aren't actually passing them all to some other function. You only pass the result of invoking the function on the last argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original code only passes one argument to the function. That is because this

```
(us.member_func(1), ...)
```

Is a fold expression that applies the comma operator. It calls all those members in sequence, but the value of the expression is just what the last invocation returns.

Assuming you want to call the member on each object, and pass all the results onto the next function, the fix also turns it into valid C++14:

```
template <typename... Us>
double func2(const Us&... us)
{
    // assume all member_func return types are non-void
    return func(us.member_func(1) ...);
}
```

Just a regular pack expansion in a functions argument list. Though there better not be any sequencing requirements between those calls. The comma operator has sequencing guarantees, the evaluation of function arguments far less so.